# Where does gravitational potential energy come from?

Tags: gravity, potential-energy

If a body with mass is a finite distance away from another body with mass, then they possess a gravitational potential energy. Consider that both the bodies didn't have any energy previously, but when they are in one another's gravitational influence they are gaining gravitational potential energy. Is this energy coming from a quantum field of gravity (just like, electric potential energy is coming from photon field and strong nuclear potential energy from gluon field)?

Is this the case? If not, where am I wrong?

Comment: AFAIK there is currently no quantum theory of gravity. Which means this won't yield an explanation. And maybe there is no answer to your question, no higher-level "why" for the attraction of masses and we'll have to understand it as an observational fact.

Comment: Re, "...both the bodies didn't have any energy previously..." and "...in one another's gravitational influence..." Two bodies are _always_ in each other's gravitational influence. Gravity does not have limited range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Total energy is a conserved quantity, so gravitational potential energy always comes from some other form of energy.

> Consider that both the bodies didn't have any energy previously

This is not possible. In order for the bodies to have gravitational potential energy now, they must have had some other form of energy previously. Or some other system must have transferred energy (work) to the bodies. A scenario where an isolated system without energy suddenly obtains energy violates the known laws of physics.

Comment: So, can that 'previous' energy be transferred from a quantum field of gravity.

Comment: @AgnibhoDutta it is probably best to learn known and experimentally confirmed physics before venturing off into completely speculative topics

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question and applies to potential energy in general.

The short answer is potential energy is often negative, while kinetic energy is positive.

*Total* Energy *T* is conserved (in Newtonian mechanics at least), so must remain the same. It is the sum of kinetic *K* and potential *V*, i.e.

$$T=K+V$$

If two bodies begin in a state where we say T=0, K=0, V=0, they fall towards each other by gravity and possess K=1000 before they collide, then right before the Collison: K=1000, V=-1000, T still equals zero.

The way to understand this is, the two bodies coming closer together are achieving a lower energy state than when they were apart, and this is where the energy of their motion "comes from." If the objects are now touching and you want to pull them back apart against their gravity, you need to input work, adding energy to the system.

This is the same as when say a Jenga tower falls over. It starts in a quiescent state, apparently with no energy, but suddenly blocks are flying everywhere each having kinetic energy.  That kinetic energy is compensated for by the decrease in gravitational potential energy, as the blocks are all closer to the ground. Or a non-gravity example: Hydrogen and oxygen gas are mixed and sitting in a tank serenely.  The system has no obvious energy. Once a spark occurs (the energy of the spark can be arbitrarily small) to begin the reaction, suddenly heat and pressure and flame are released seemingly from nowhere. This energy came from the change in potential energy, as the $H$ and $O$ atoms in the form of $H_2O$ are now in a lower energy state (electromagnetically) than they were as $H_2$ and $O_2$.  This is a general principlein physics.

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy depends upon the relative position of various parts of a system. In this case it depends on the distance between the two bodies. It will be highest at infinite distance, and will reduce as distance gets shorter. This is because, the energy is needed to separate the two masses. 
Even if we assume that the two bodies are in completely different universe, and now you place the two bodies in the same universe at a distance 'R', you will need to provide energy to the system to be in that configuration.

Comment: Sir,  I want to know as an object free falls, it needs energy. Where is this energy coming from? Even, if energy is needed to put something in a configuration, where is that energy coming from?

Comment: Consider the object and the earth as a system of two masses separated by distance 'h'. As the distance between the two reduces, the gravitational potential energy reduces, which is converted to kinetic energy. Now coming to your question, someone has to provide the energy to separate this object and earth by distance 'h'. This can be given by a man who throws the object at an height 'h'.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say two identical identically spinning bodies have a lot of spinning energy.

A distant observer observes these two bodies to move into each others gravitational influence. Said observer sees the spinning rate to decrease. As spinning energy is angular momentum times angular velocity, and as angular momentum is conserved, then the spinning energy must decrease, assuming that the observed slowing down is caused by real slowing down. That assumption is a correct assumption, although some people may say it's an effect of light propagation - those people are wrong.

So here we have a case were the source of energy is clear, right?

Case 2:

Let us say two identical identically hot bodies have a lot of thermal energy.

A distant observer observes these two bodies to move into each others gravitational influence. Said observer sees the temperature to decrease. The thermal energy must decrease, assuming that the observed cooling down is caused by real cooling down. That assumption is a correct assumption, although some people may say it's an effect of light propagation - those people are wrong.

Comment: This argument shows that you are trying to say that gravity is relevant only in case of rotating bodies.

Comment: @AgnibhoDutta No.   I will add analysis of hot bodies to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You said that one should assume two bodies some distance apart from each other, with each having "mass".

Later you say that they previously did not have energy.

If an object has mass, it'll have energy this is clearly verified from the energy-mass equivalence equation, yet it could have energy and no mass. Take light as an example.

Plus having another body with mass means that body $1$ has the ability to do work on body $2$ and the same applies to body $2$, although work isn't done since the force applied isn't enough to move the bodies some distance, however, each body has the potential to do work.

$2$ Where does Gravitational potential energy come from?

It is due to the natural attraction between any two masses due to gravity. But I believe that you should've rather asked about the source of gravity, since gravitational potential energy is one of its effects.

Based on relativity, gravity is caused by the curving of the space-time fabric of space by which objects' masses start moving toward each other.

It is important to mention that the source and nature of gravity is still under research in terms of quantum mechanics, if you're meaning particles, where the phenomenon of quantum gravity is still actively researched.

Comment: You are trying to say that mass is converted to gravitational potential energy

Comment: Mass could be converted into kinetic and potential energy, when it is at rest its energy is totally potential. It is converted into kinetic energy as work is done on it. So, mass would be converted into gravitational potential energy if the force that causes the mass to do work is gravity. For example, we say that a ball is gaining gravitational potential energy as it is lifted above earth's surface, since the work that is to be done due to gravity increases.

Answer (score -2):

The first question we need to answer is whether gravity surrounding a planet requires energy at all?

Think of a bar magnet. There is a magnetic field surrounding a bar magnet. And that magnetic field will never disappear. It will stay forever without requiring any energy from the magnet. That is the virtual electrons that surround the magnet will never disappear and do not cause a loss of energy inside the magnet.

Now think of a planet. Something inside that planet is causing the warping of SpaceTime around it. Some people would say that the planet is emitting gravitons (I would say that gravitons are simply virtual gluons).  Whatever it is, it does not cause any loss of energy to the planet. That warping of SpaceTime will remain forever. Even if the planet is blown to dust across the solar system, the warping of SpaceTime remains.

So now we have to look at the actual origin of that warping of SpaceTime. If it is caused by the emission of some virtual particle, then the originating particle (what I believe to be the glueon) is simply spinning in place and causing that excitation of the field surrounding it. But a planet will never run out of gravity. The energy will never be drained so long as those virtual particles exist.

Imagine if we took two planets and suspended them just a couple of meters apart with giant cables connected to other planets. These two planets would never lose their potential energy. It would never ever wear out or dissipate.

So I would say that in the situation you describe, questions about the conservation of energy become meaningless. The warping of SpaceTime supersedes these ideas.